# PHP DateTime diff returns wrong result with timezone

Tags: php, datetime

**Here is my code:**

```
$time = '2017-11-13 05:00:20';
$adsTime = new DateTime($time);
$NOW = new DateTime();
$london = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');
$NOW->setTimezone($london);
$diff = $adsTime->diff($NOW);

echo $adsTime->format('h'). "\n"; // ads hour return 5
echo $NOW->format('h'). "\n"; // now hour return 5
echo $diff->format('%h'). "\n"; // it return wrong
```

The problem is `diff` return wrong, ads hour is 5, now hour 5, it should return 0 not another number.

**[Online Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ae07f5ad0e054eef758ab608a6ec2eb175dee817)**

Comment: If the hours are the same but the timezones are different, the difference between the times will be the difference between the timezones.

Comment: which timezones? server timezone set to `london` and here also set to `london` . after all, what should i do? i need to it return zero when hour are same. @Barmar

Comment: Then just subtract the hours, don't use `diff()`.

Comment: @Barmar Kinda think i can't do this, because this script used to get diff between ads date and now date, in all case, year, months, days, hours see this please [Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/edc75cd6091370bdf1ceb4eee75f54823acd13fd) I need it return zero to show the time: JUST NOW

Comment: There is no other solution?

Comment: Timezone for your demo is `US/Pacific`, what do you expect to see if the $adsTime is a different timezone?

Comment: @MarkBaker US/Pacific ?? no, that is `$london = new DateTimeZone('Europe/London');` where you see `US/Pacific`

Comment: So in practise it should be `$adsTime = new DateTime($time, $london);`?

Comment: `$time = $ad["time"];
$adsTime = new DateTime($time);`  in face `$ad["time"]` return `'2017-11-13 05:00:20'` which based on London time. server time set to London by default @MarkBaker

Comment: If the server time is set to London, why are you using `setTimeZone` to set the timezone?

Comment: In fact, after i face this problem,  for making sure added london timezone, but nothing changed, @Barmar / Better safe than sorry!

Comment: And also i added timezone to `NOW` for you, to see London time. @Barmar

Comment: I don't see any edit of the question.

Comment: I said update? no, i mean if i didn't add timezone, you get NOW in your localtime or UTC, i added to show you, or anyone want to answer see london time. @Barmar